# Makefile:2227: recipe for target 's-tm-texi' failed

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, makefile, cygwin

```
Verify that you have permission to grant a GFDL license for all new text in 
tm.texi, then copy it to ../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/doc/tm.texi.

Makefile:2227: recipe for target 's-tm-texi' failed 

make[3]: ***[s-tm-texi] Error 1 

make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... 

rm gcc.pod 

make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/contrib/gcc-build/gcc'

Makefile:4218: recipe for target 'all-stage1-gcc' failed 

make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2 

make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/contrib/gcc-build' 

Makefile:17016: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed 

make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2 

make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/contrib/gcc-build' 

Makefile:887: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is what I get from typing in the command "make -j 4" based upon the directions from here: http://www.matpack.de/cygwin/index.html and from what I've read this is not a bad error, but I cannot find out how to fix it.  Can anyone throw some help my way?

Comment: What are the bunch of lines directly above this snippet? What's on line 2227 of the `Makefile`?

Comment: build/genmddeps.exe ../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/config/i386/i386.md > tmp-mddeps

case `echo X|tr X '\101'` in \

  A) tr -d '\015' < tmp-tm.texi > tmp2-tm.texi ;; \

  *) tr -d '\r' < tmp-tm.texi > tmp2-tm.texi ;; \

esac

mv tmp2-tm.texi tmp-tm.texi

/bin/sh ../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/../move-if-change tmp-tm.texi tm.texi

/bin/sh ../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/../move-if-change tmp-mddeps mddeps.mk

echo timestamp > s-mddeps

/bin/sh: cmp: command not found



is above it

maybe-install-etc \

is on the makefile

@EtanReisner

Comment: I'm going to go with `/bin/sh: cmp: command not found` being the problem.

Comment: Is this something that can be fixed with a download? I am very new to installing cygwin, and need some assistance with this.@EtanReisner

Comment: It should be available as part of cygwin yes. Might be in a `cmp` package or `diffutils` or something like that.

Comment: I found a diffutils install in cygwin, and it seems to have fixed my first issue.  Will update this if there is another issue down the line.  Thank you very much for the prompt answers!